# When to use Ember.computed

Tags: ember.js

I've noticed in many examples defining computed properties with `Ember.computed` but I don't exactly understand what it does. Is there a difference between these two code examples?

```
fullname: Ember.computed ->
  @get('firstName') + @get('lastName')
.property('firstName', 'lastName')

fullname: ( ->
  @get('firstName') + @get('lastName')
).property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

Comment: Check this http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

Comment: So by default these produce exactly the same results? Can I use Ember.computed even with prototype extensions enabled without a trouble or ember doing something twice for that matter? I like the first example because of the lack of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your top example should read:

```
fullname: Ember.computed 'firstName','lastName', ->
  "#{@get('firstName')} #{@get('lastName')}"
```

With our corrected syntax,  both examples will end return an instance of Ember's `Ember.ComputedProperty` class, more or less a mutated Function object. In terms of behavior they are identical.